# Zoom G1XON noise issue

Tags: electric-guitar, live-sound

I am a beginner and playing acoustic for last 2 and 1/2 year. After this i grew interest in Electric, so i bought a Squier Strat and as per suggestion of my music teacher a Zoom G1Xon. When i connect the processor directly to the home theater/ P.A. system, it sounds awesome, but when i connect it to my PC for recording the tracks (Using Adobe Audition 2015 or Nuendo 6.5) it catches a plenty of noise. I initially replaced the cables and the batteries also tried various tones but all in vain. As a result the tracks recorded by me have a plenty of noise. Is there any problem with the processor? or everyone has the same issue? Please suggest.
Regards,
Kunal

Comment: Are you using the USB or Jack to connect to computer?

Comment: Is the PC a laptop or desktop? Have you tried using a ground loop isolator between the G1Xon and the PC?

Comment: I had another multi effects processor and it was noisy as hell when connected directly to my laptop. You need something between them to prepare signal.

Comment: Dear David, I connect the processor to my laptop using 1/4-1/8" cables..

Comment: Dear Topo, I use a Dell Inspiron 5520 laptop. I have not tried Ground Loop Islolater, even i don't know whats it? I will google it now.. If you know, please elaborate. Regards

Comment: Dear Teodozjan, are you referring a Focusrite Scarlett like device?

Comment: Connect using UPS. If problem still exists run processor using battery power. If noise still there the problem is with your computer.

Comment: Quick question - what type of noise? Are we talking mains hum (50 or 60Hz) or interference from other devices?

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is a year too late but I thought I would answer for future viewers with the same problem.

This is exactly as 'teodozjan' says in the comments above, the noise is being generated from the on-board sound card in the laptop. What you need is an audio interface such as the Focusrite Scarlett, M-Audio M-Track, etc. These devices have much better analog to digital conversion than on-board sound cards hence far better signal to noise ratio.

Even a really cheap audio interface such as the Behringer UM2 U-Phoria Audiophile (£45 on Amazon at time of writing) will be considerably better than being plugged straight into the laptop.

Some multi-fx pedals can now be used as an audio interface themselves, check out the Zoom G3. You can plug this pedal into your laptop/PC via USB and all the analog to digital conversion is then done by the pedal.